# 元のソースコードのメソッドの場所をなるべく同じにしてくれるようなテキストエディタ

Tags: atom-editor, sublimetext

現在、Borland C++ Builder 6で作成されたソースコードをRAD-Studio10.3でもビルドできるように移行作業を行っております。

取り掛かり始めの時は、とりあえずすべてのソースコードを新規プロジェクトに追加させてビルドエラー内容からコード修正などを実施してなるべく元のソースコードの形を大きく変更することなく修正作業を行っていました。
しかし、エラー内容から明確な原因がわからないことが多く、一旦諦めてしまいました。

その後、新規プロジェクトからコンポーネントを1個ずつ追加して、エラーが出たらその都度修正を実施して、エラーがないことを確認しながら作業を進めています。

作業がかなり進んできたのですが、コンポーネントを追加してその時にメソッドのコーディングもしていった結果、移行元のソースコードのメソッドの場所がバラバラになってしまっている状態です。

とりあえず一旦整理や、差分ソフトで元ソースとの違いなどを確認するため、元のソースとなるべく場所を同じにしてくれるようなエディタソフトや機能などを教えて下さい。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 「メソッドの場所」とは開いたファイルの中で何行目の辺りに記述されているか、ということですか？ / どこに記述するかはエディタを使う人間次第な気もします。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。元のソースと修正実施したソースを比較したい時などに、differ見たいな差分表示ソフトとかで確認する時はなるべく同じ行にしておいた方がいいかなと思いました。ただ、開発環境で

Comment: 開発環境でコンポーネントのダブルクリックでメソッドが自動で配置されるのはプログラミング的には楽ですね。メソッド一覧とかで１個１個確認したほうがいいのかもですね。